# scalatest intercept vs a[Exception] should be thrownBy

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm testing some `Future` that fails, and I tried it in two different ways, one that works:

```
intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
  Await.result(dao.findById("some_id"), Duration.Inf)
}
```

and one that dosen't:

```
a[NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy dao.findById("some_id")
```

It happened to me before, and I'm trying to figure out why is that..?

Would love to get some help understanding this.

`findById` simply throws `NoSuchElementException` if it fails:

```
  def findById(id: String): Future[Person] = {
    collection.find(json(Vendor.PersonId -> id))
      .requireOne[Person] recover {
      case NoSuchResultException => throw new NoSuchElementException
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the `Future` is not handle correctly.

Given this definition:

```
def findById(id: String): Future[Person] = {
  collection.find(json(Vendor.PersonId -> id))
    .requireOne[Person] recover {
     case NoSuchResultException => throw new NoSuchElementException
    }
}
```

the `recover` will map a `NoSuchResultException` into a `throw new NoSuchElementException`, but it always wrapped inside the `Future`.

This means that returned object will be a failed `Future` and the method won't throw any exception.

To handle such case you could, for example, mix-in your test class with the `ScalaFutures` trait in scalatest. This helps you to handle the future like

```
dao.findById("some_id").failed.futureValue should be a[NoSuchElementException]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider if this was the implementation:

```
def findById(id: String): Future[Person] = Future {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  throw new NoSuchElementException()
}
```

Calling `findById` does not itself throw the exception. It returns this future immediately. The exception is thrown within the `Future` that it returns, so it only surfaces when you `Await` on the result, or otherwise access the result of the future.